# How to label a single Tick mark at a specified tick location

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am attempting to annotate a graph in a very simple manner.  This is 2D plot of a function over a range of x-values, for example, let's say 0 to 15.  By default, my plot labels the Tick marks as 0, 5, 10, 15, ...

What I would like to do is at the value of 10 on the x-axes (in this simple example)  add the additional label of "L" (for example, a single letter) to the Tick Mark at the value of 10.

I have been experimenting and reading up on the documentation and I find no way to do this so far.

Comment: Have you looked up [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) in the documentation?

Comment: @Edmund -- sure I have but I tried lots of variations and they all seem to want a number as a tick mark label.  I want the label to be nothing other than the letter L which is not a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above you need to look at the `Ticks` option of `Plot`.  There you will see that you can use labels for the tick markers.  In the **Details** section look at the 4th form $\left\{\left\{x_1,\text{label}_1\right\},\left\{x_2,\text{label}_2\right\},\ldots \right\}$. This is the form you want.

Once you start specifying `Ticks` you have to specify all of them. For this case you can use `Range` and `Replace` so you don't have to type them all out.

```
Range[0,15,5]
(* {0, 5, 10, 15} *)
```

These are the `Ticks` for the axis. You want $10$ to be `Replace`d with $\text{L}$ using the `Ticks` format above.

```
Range[0, 15, 5] /. {10 -> {10, "L"}}
(* {0, 5, {10, "L"}, 15} *)
```

Now throw that into `Plot`

Plot[x, {x, 0, 15}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 15, 5] /. {10 -> {10, "L"}}, Automatic}]

[image]

Comment: -- Thanks.  My problem was that I was not specifying each Tick mark.  Given the syntax of the specification where the Tick value number was required, I figured that you could specify individual Tick marks.  In fact, I think it makes more sense if it worked the way I thought it did so you could specify all, or some, or one of the Tick marks per your pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[
 Sin@x, {x, -Pi, Pi},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {{-Pi/2, 0, {Pi/2, Row[{Pi/2, " L"}], 0.01}}, None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the example.  But, this is annotating the frame box and I would like to annotate the actual X-axis.  Is that possible?